# How can I remove all characters inside angle brackets python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.8

How can I remove all characters inside angle brackets including the brackets in a string? How can I also remove all the text between ("\r\n") and ("."+"any 3 characters") Is this possible? I am currently using the solution by @xkcdjerry

e.g

````
body = """Dear Students roads etc. you place a tree take a snapshot, then when you place a\r\nbuilding, take a snapshot. Place at least 5-6 objects and then have 5-6\r\nsnapshots. Please keep these snapshots with you as everyone will be asked\r\nto share them during the class.\r\n\r\nI am attaching one PowerPoint containing instructions and one video of\r\nexplanation for your reference.\r\n\r\nKind regards,\r\nTeacher Name\r\n zoom_0.mp4\r\n<https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UX-klOfVhbefvbhZvIWijaBdQuLgh_-Uru4_1QTkth/view?usp=drive_web>"""
d = re.compile("\r\n.+?\\....")
body = d.sub('', body)
a = re.compile("<.*?>")
body = a.sub('', body)
print(body)```

For some reason the output is fine except that it has:
```gle.com/file/d/1UX-klOfVhbefvbhZvIWijaBdQuLgh_-Uru4_1QTkth/view?usp=drive_web>
````

randomly attached to the end How can I fix it.

Comment: That's because the string is in the input...Look at the end of `body`

Comment: More clearly,you input has the string `<https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UX-klOfVhbefvbhZvIWijaBd
   ...: QuLgh_-Uru4_1QTkth/view?usp=drive_web>` in the end.Because the `\r\n…….goo`part has been replaced by the regex,you end up with `gle.com/file/d/1UX-klOfVhbefvbhZvIWijaBdQuLgh_-Uru4_1QTkth/view?usp=drive_web>`

Answer (score 2):

## Answer

Your problem can be solved by a regex:
Put this into the shell:

```py
import re
a=re.compile("<.*?>")
a.sub('',"Keep this part of the string< Remove this part>Keep This part as well")
```

Output:

```py
'Keep this part of the stringKeep This part as well'
```

Second question:

```py
import re
re.compile("\r\n.*?\\..{3}")
a.sub('',"Hello\r\nFilename.png")
```

Output:

```py
'Hello'
```

## Breakdown

Regex is a robust way of finding, replacing, and mutating small strings inside bigger ones, for further reading,consult https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html. Meanwhile, here are the breakdowns of the regex information used in this answer:

`.` means any char.
`*?` means as many of the before as needed but as little as possible(non-greedy match)
So `.*?` means any number of characters but as little as possible.
Note: The reason there is a `\\.` in the second regex is that a `.` in the match needs to be escaped by a `\`, which in its turn needs to be escaped as `\\`

The methods:
`re.compile(patten:str)` compiles a regex for farther use.
`regex.sub(repl:str,string:str)` replaces every match of `regex` in `string` with repl.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I edited the answer because a specific string that i tried wasn't working. Thanks for all the help so far.